# if no data will be displayed message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have table in Html and table's rows are repeated angular-js directive called ng-repeat. And I am searching and ordering filters text input that have ng-model directive so I can filter any data. I use ui-bootstrap in my angularjs app.

Everything works but if user searchs and has no data in table then I want to show message with ng-show directive.

Here is my code.

```
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in HocaListesiDetails.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), (currentPage*itemsPerPage)) | filter:Search | orderBy:orderUserSelected " ng-style="item.TabloId == selectedHoca && {'background-color':'#ccc'}" ng-click="hocaSec(item.TabloId)">
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.AdSoyad}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.TcNumarasi}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.Telefon}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.DogumYeri}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.DogumTarihi | formattedFilter | date}}</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr ng-show="FilteredHocaListesiDetails.length == 0" style="background:#fff;">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                                        <p class="text-center">Aradığınız kişi bulunamadı.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<tr ng-show="(FilteredHocaListesiDetails| filter:search).length == 0" style="background:#fff;">
                            <td colspan="6">
                                <div class="alert alert-info">
                                    <p class="text-center">Aradığınız kişi bulunamadı.</p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to include "filter:Search" in ng-show to check the length.

<tr ng-show="(list | filter:search).length==0">No Results</tr>